# Proving that a $P_X(A)$ is a probability by Kolmogorov's Definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, 2^\Omega, P)$ be a discrete Prob. Space with $\Omega$ finite and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We need to prove that for $A \subset X(\Omega)$ the value of $P_X (A) := P(X^{-1}(A)) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \in A\})$  is a probability.

So far I have used $A=X(\Omega)$ as the case to show the first axiom that $P(\Omega) = 1$. It is known that for finite $\Omega$ the second axiom of Kolmogorov's definition reduces to "If A and B are disjoint subsets of $\Omega$ then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$." I have tried to use this by letting A and B be two disjoint subsets in $X(\Omega)$. However after trying it I don't think this is a good approach. My main issue with it is trying to split the two probabilities.

I am not really looking for a complete answer as that would spoil the fun, but a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Firslty, you want to show that $P_X$ is a probability on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, not that $P_X(A)$ is a probability (which is just a value). Yes, you've checked the first one correctly, that is $P_X(\mathbb R) = \mathbb P(X^{-1}(\mathbb R)) = \mathbb P(\Omega) = 1$. Nonnegativity is obvious. For the last one, take disjoint $A,B$ borel subsets of $\mathbb R$, then $ P_X(A \cup B) = \mathbb P(X^{-1}(A \cup B)) = \mathbb P(X^{-1}(A) \cup X^{-1}(B))$ by preimage properties. Can you show that $X^{-1}(A),X^{-1}(B)$ are disjoint and use that $\mathbb P$ is a probability to conclude?

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!